# Select EVERY rows where id is NOT distinct

Tags: mysql

I'm a little bit in confusion and I'm asking help by some guru

I have this table (named "mytable")

```
ID   |   Colum_a   |   Column_b
121      100             NULL
122      150             200
123      100             100
124       50             NULL
125     NULL              5
```

To select the id, I use a simple query like this

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE Colum_a > 0 OR Column_b > 0
```

and I have, obviously, this result:

```
ID
121
122
123
124
125
```

Now, my "head scratch" (and here I'm in confusion...).
I need to "separate" both columns (Column_a and Column_b) allowing the "duplicate" the id.

To be more clear, I need a result like this (to use in a future foreach loop, php):

```
ID   |   Result   
121      100
122      150            
122      200            
123      100    
123      100
124       50
125        5
```

I tried with this query but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE Column_a > 0 OR Column_b > 0 IN
(SELECT ID FROM mytable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are the blank values? 0? ''? ' '?  NULL?

Comment: Blank values are NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps using `union all`

```
select ID, Colum_a  as res from mytable WHERE Column_a > 0
union all 
select ID, Colum_b  as res from mytable WHERE Column_b > 0
order by ID asc;
```